# Finding equation of plane passing through a line

Tags: vectors, 3d

If a line has the equation  $ \frac{y}{a} + \frac{z}{b} =1, x = 0 $ how can we find the equation of the plane passing through it.

The method that i know is to convert the line to the symmetric form, and solve it further (which indeed gives me the solution of the question).

But the solution said that, any plane passing through this line will be of the form :-

$ \frac{y}{a} + \frac{z}{b} -1 + \lambda\ x=0$ .

I wish to know how can one derive this equation mathematically?

Comment: There will be infinitely many planes, a family of planes. Since the given line is the intersection of the two planes $P_1: x=0$ and $P_2: by+az=ab$, all planes $P$ that also have this line will be given by $P_1+\lambda P_2=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Anurag. Can we make a general statement that for any line $L$, and plane $P1$, such that the line lies in the plane, then equation of a plane passing through the line can be given by P2 = L + λ P1$ ?

Comment: That is not true, because $L+\lambda P_1$ will only give you things "within" the plane $P_1$ (as $L$ itself lies in the plane). So, a plane that is say perpendicular to $P_1$ and has the line $L$ in it cannot be written as $L+\lambda P_1$. For example, take $P_1$ as $xy-$plane and the line $L:= \{(t,0,0) \, | \, t \in \mathbb{R}\}$ passing through the origin.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification. So, in your example, to find the plane through the line, which's x-axis, we need to find 2 planes passing through x axis, which we can easily say are $y=0, z= 0$ , and then say plane is $P1+ \lambda\ P2 =0$